# Why is the website not loading after a click with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, click

I'm trying to load all products of a website where around 20 products are shown and then a "show more" button has to be klicked to load more products. I can see that the button is klicked when I execute the code, but the content of the website is not loaded. In the end a loop shall be built to load all the products, but to do so the content first has to be visible.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.galaxus.ch/de/s2/sector/haushalt-2'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\DRIVERS\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

sleep(3)

element = driver.find_element_by_id('pageFoot')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight-5);", element)
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)

sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pageContent"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[5]/div/button/span').click()
sleep(20)

driver.close()
```

I've also tried to click on other objects within the website but the access is then denied.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to site. Try this locator for your button.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".styled__DeprecatedStyledButton-sc-1wug1tr-1.isotoG")
```

If you will still have a problem, than scroll into a different element. For example to this button. As I see it is not visible if you scroll to the very bottom.
Also, for debugging `time.sleep()` is ok, but in real projects you should use only explicit/implicit waits, with some exclusions where `time.sleep()` is the only option.